# How to remove ˆM chars?

Tags: windows, bash, cat

I have a file generated from windows that I have to paste into a script under linux.
My script works fine, except for the fact that at the end of every line I got a ^M char.

How can I remove it with bash?

Currently my script is:

```
#/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for CUSTOMER in `cat exp.csv`
do
    echo $CUSTOMER
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [dos2unix](http://www.bastet.com/) on `exp.csv` before further processing.

Comment: dos2unix should be the one you want if you're operating on a Windows file in Linux.

Answer (score 5):

^M should be windows newline \r, therefore you just need to remove all \r
You can achieve this using the tr tool, which you can call from your bash script, this is from the wikipedia article (i did not verify it):

```
tr -d '\r' < inputfile > outputfile
```

Therefore, from bash it should be something like

```
VAR=`echo -n $CUSTOMER | tr -d '\r'`
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this a lot using `tr`. The CR character is 013 in octal:

```
tr -d '\013' < $FILE
```

So in your loop, that would just be

```
for CUSTOMER in `tr -d '\013' < exp.csv`
```

Answer (score 0):

dos2unix command ont he file

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to remove bad `char M` from your file

1. use command `dos2unix file_name`
2. open file in vi editor, go to
   command mode and type `:%s/ctrl+v ctrl+m//g` this will remove all bad
   chars from you file. now use `:wq` for save and exit
3. `sed -e "s/^M//" filename(exist file name) > newfilename(new name)`

   sed -e "s/^M//" filename(exist file name) > newfilename(new name)

NOTE: to find bad chars on unix server hit below command for all java files

```
find . -name "*.java*"  -type f | xargs grep -l ^M *
```

Similarly you can use `"*.*"` instead of `"*.java"` for all type of files